# Evenly spaced table grid from current text position to end of page

Tags: tables

I want to design an assignment sheets, which should look like this:

[image]

So I place the title, and then I want to set a table of N times M assignments (N and M vary from assignment sheet to assignment sheet), that is:

- N times evenly spaced across the page width
- M times evenly spaced across the rest of the page height

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the assignment content there? How do you type that?

Comment: Is there any feedback on the given solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A version with `tcolorbox` and `tcbraster` feature.

The command `\assignmentsheet` has 4 arguments:

- 1st: Options to `tcbraster`.
- 2nd: Number of rows
- 3rd: Number of columns
- 4th. Content (a bunch of `tcolorbox` statements)

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\tcbset{plainbox/.style={enhanced jigsaw,boxrule=1pt, sharp corners, colback=yellow!10!white,colbacktitle={red}, coltitle={white},notitle}}

\newtcbox[auto counter]{assignbox}[1][]{
  plainbox,
  title={Assignment},
  #1
}


\newcommand{\assignmentsheet}[4][]{%
  \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=#3, raster rows=#2,raster equal height,#1,raster width=\textwidth, raster height=\textheight,breakable]
    #4%
  \end{tcbraster}
}

\begin{document}
\assignmentsheet{5}{4}{%
  \assignbox{Do this}
  \assignbox{Do that}
  \assignbox{Do something different}
  \assignbox{Do the right thing}
  \assignbox{Do this}
  \assignbox{Do that}
  \assignbox{Do something different}
  \assignbox{Do the right thing}
  \assignbox{Do this}
  \assignbox{Do that}
  \assignbox{Do something different}
  \assignbox{Do the right thing}
  \assignbox{Do this}
  \assignbox{Do that}
  \assignbox{Do something different}
  \assignbox{Do the right thing}
  \assignbox{Do this}
  \assignbox{Do that}
  \assignbox{Do something different}
  \assignbox{Do the right thing}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It may look as follows (package `labels` used):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{labels}

\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}

\LabelCols=3% Number of columns of labels per page
\LabelRows=8% Number of rows of labels per page
\LeftBorder=8mm% Space added to left border of each label
\RightBorder=8mm% Space added to right border of each label
\TopBorder=9mm% Space to leave at top of sheet
\BottomBorder=2mm% Space to leave at bottom of sheet



\begin{document}

\begin{labels}

Załącznik 1

Załącznik 2

Załącznik 3

Załącznik 4

Załącznik 5

Załącznik 6

Załącznik 7

Załącznik 8

Załącznik 9

Załącznik 10

Załącznik 11

Załącznik 12

Załącznik 13

Załącznik 14

Załącznik 15

Załącznik 16

Załącznik 17

Załącznik 18

Załącznik 19

Załącznik 20

Załącznik 21

Załącznik 22

Załącznik 23

Załącznik 24

Załącznik 25

Załącznik 26

Załącznik 27

Załącznik 28

Załącznik 29

Załącznik 30

Dokument 1

Dokument 2

Dokument 3

Dokument 4

Dokument 5

Dokument 6

Dokument 7

Dokument 8

Dokument 9

Dokument 10

Wrocław, 10.01.2005


\end{labels}

\end{document}
```